# Error in AWS RDS DUMP

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database, rds, dump

When I take database dump from AWS RDS, it is not throwing any error but when i restore dump;found some tables are missing from it.I also tried echo $? and it showing exit status 2.
Please advise.

Comment: More information is needed.  Is this MySQL? Postgres?  RDS or RDS+Aurora?   What gives you the error 2 -- the dump or the restore?

Comment: Its MySQL RDS.And when i take dump then it gives exit code 2. i tried below command for dump                                                                                                             "mysqldump -h work23.cs45m24rl.ap-north.rds.amazonaws.com -u rahul -p wordpress > wordpress.sql"                                                                                             It showing complete and not throwing any error but when i try to check exit status using echo $? found exit status code 2.After that when i restore this dump i found that some tables are missing from it.

Comment: `perror 2` --> "OS error code   2:  No such file or directory"